# Remove list from list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a simple function that needs to remove a certain element from a list. The list has 3 lists inside, and I want to search the 2nd one for a given value. This 2nd list's elements are also lists (id x y).

My function receives a `list` and and `id` as arguments, and it has to remove the element from the second list that has that id.

```
(defun rem (list id)
  (dolist (var (nth 1 list))
    (cond (equal id (nth 0 var))
          (delete var (nth 1 list))))
)
```

I search the second list of the given list, and when I find the element with `id`, I delete it. The problem is that I'm always getting `NIL`. I tried with function `remove` as well, but the result is the same.

Comment: Do you want the function to modify its argument `list`, to produce a return value (and what exactly?), or both?

Comment: This code doesn't simply return `nil`, it generates outright errors.  If you've got code that returns `nil`, please show it. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this  code, and describing them is actually longer than constructing a working example, so I'll show a working version first, and then walk through the code that you provided.  Please read through that second section and be sure you understand the issues in the original code, though.

### A working version

Based on your description, you want to *remove* each element of the *second* element of `list` whose *first* element is `id`. I'm not sure exactly what it is that you want to return, but assuming that it's like `list`, but with the new second element, you can do something like the following.  I emphasized certain words in that paragraph, because they're important for solving this problem.  You have an `id`, and you want to remove things from a sequence that have that `id`.  You can do that with [`remove`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) (or `delete`) by calling `(remove id sequence :key <key>)`, where `key` is a function that extracts a value from the sequence elements to compare against `id`.  You want to remove those elements from `(second list)` whose `first` is `id`.  You'd use

```
(remove id (second list) :key 'first)
```

to do that.  In context, you'd get a function like this:

```
(defun bex-remove (list id)
  (list (first list)
        (remove id (second list) :key 'first)
        (third list)))
```

Here's an example:

```
(bex-remove '((1 2 3 4)                 ; values don't matter
              ((id-a x1 y1)
               (id-b x2 y2)
               (id-a x3 y3)
               (id-b x4 y4))
              (5 6 7 8))                ; values don't matter
            'id-a)

;=> ((1 2 3 4) ((ID-B X2 Y2) (ID-B X4 Y4)) (5 6 7 8))
```

### Issues with your code

There are a few issues:

1. You shouldn't try to define a function named `rem`.
2. You've got syntax errors in your code.
3. `delete` doesn't necessarily have the side effects that your code presupposes that it does.
4. `dolist`, by default, returns `nil`.

In more detail:

There's already a function named [`REM`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mod_r.htm) in the Common Lisp package that computes a remainder.  Trying to evaluate your definition in SBCL signals an error:

```
Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when setting fdefinition of
REM while in package COMMON-LISP-USER.
   [Condition of type SYMBOL-PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR]
See also:
  SBCL Manual, Package Locks [:node]
  Common Lisp Hyperspec, 11.1.2.1.2 [:section]
```

You get a similar error in CLISP (with which you've tagged the question, so I assume it's the implementation that you're using):

```
[1]> (defun rem (x) x) ; not the same as your definition, but still a function named rem

** - Continuable Error
DEFUN/DEFMACRO(REM): #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Ignore the lock and proceed
The following restarts are also available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
```

We'll rename your function `%rem` so that we can continue, and we'll see what happens.  When try compile the adjusted definition in SBCL, we get a warnings about undefined variables `delete` and `equal`.

```
; --> IF COND 
; ==>
;   (IF DELETE
;       (PROGN VAR (NTH 1 LIST))
;       NIL)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: DELETE

; ==>
;   (IF EQUAL
;       (PROGN ID (NTH 0 VAR))
;       (COND (DELETE VAR (NTH 1 LIST))))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: EQUAL
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variables:
;     DELETE EQUAL
;   caught 2 WARNING conditions
```

In CLISP you'll have to compile before you get similar warnings:

```
CL-USER> (defun %rem (list id)
           (dolist (var (nth 1 list))
             (cond (equal id (nth 0 var))
                   (delete var (nth 1 list))))
           )
%REM
CL-USER> (compile '%rem)
WARNING: in %REM : EQUAL is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING: in %REM : DELETE is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
%REM
2
2
```

The syntax of [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) is `(cond (test expr*)*)`, which means that each test and its associated expressions need to be wrapped in parentheses.  Updated to fix that, we now have:

```
(defun %rem (list id)
  (dolist (var (nth 1 list))
    (cond 
      ((equal id (nth 0 var))
       (delete var (nth 1 list))))))
```

When we compile that, we still get some warnings in SBCL, but CLISP doesn't generate similar warnings, even during compilation:

```
; in: DEFUN %REM
;     (DELETE VAR (NTH 1 LIST))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of DELETE should not be discarded.
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of DELETE should not be discarded.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions
```

What this is telling us is that you really need to *save* the results from `delete`.  `delete` can modify a list in arbitrary ways, and yet isn't required to modify anything at all.  For instance, in the following code, the value of the variable `x` isn't modified, although `(delete 1 x)` *does* return a list `(2 3)`.

```
CL-USER> (let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
           (delete 1 x)          ; could return, e.g, (cdr x)
           x)
;=> (1 2 3)
```

So what you're probably trying to write is:

```
(defun %rem (list id)
  (dolist (var (nth 1 list))
    (cond                                    ; or (when (equal id (nth 0 var))
      ((equal id (nth 0 var))                ;      (setf (nth 1 list) ...))
       (setf (nth 1 list) 
             (delete var (nth 1 list)))))))
```

This code isn't likely to do much that's useful.  One, you're modifying `(nth 1 list)` while you're iterating over it, which is unlikely to have good results. I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do, exactly.  Since you're iterating over `(nth 1 list)`, `list` must have the form

```
(<first-element> (var1 var2 ...) ...)
```

and since you take `(nth 0 var)`, then each `vari` must also be a list, so list has the form

```
(<first-element> ((<elt10> ...) (<elt20> ...) ...) ...)
```

Regardless, your `dolist` will still return `nil`. The syntax for [`dolist`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm) is

```
dolist (var list-form [result-form]) declaration* {tag | statement}*
```

and that optional `result-form` defaults to `nil`.  I'm not sure exactly what you want to return, but maybe it's list, in which case you'd do

```
(dolist (var list list)
  …)
```

For instance:

```
(let ((list (list 1 2 3)))
  (dolist (x list)                ; return default (nil)
    (+ x x)))
;=> NIL

(let ((list (list 1 2 3)))
  (dolist (x list (reverse list)) ; return something
    (+ x x)))
;=> (3 2 1)
```

Comment: Sorry about the rem. The function isn't named like that, but I changed it to simplify things here, I was just unlucky that it already exists. :) . The original name is a long one in my native language, so I thought it would be good to change it. I'm not getting any errors or warnings when compiling though. Can it be because I'm in Mac OS and installed clisp through Macports? I'm going to read what you wrote with more attention now, and hopefully come up with a solution. Thanks in advance for the excellent reply!

Comment: Notice how I compiled in the REPL;  I first defined the function and then explicitly compiled it.  Even without the warnings, you should have been encountering errors because the variables `delete` and `equal` were undefined.   I don't think the code in the question could have been what you were running.